# Whether to share at thesis defense where I have submitted pertaining papers to

Tags: thesis, paper-submission, defense

I have submitted journal articles that come from my thesis.

When defending the thesis, is it a good idea to give the names of the journals to which those pertaining papers were submitted to?

Comment: What details to you want to provide to whom? Your sentence structure makes no sense, sorry.

Comment: I need to provide the name of journal which I submitted the article resulted from my thesis. In my defense time.

Comment: "A resulted paper of thesis" - you mean, you wrote the thesis, and then made a paper out of it? Or the other way around: you wrote a paper, and included it in your thesis?

Comment: I submitted a paper from the work done in my thesis. By details, I just mean "The name of Journal which I submitted the paper to that".

Comment: Why haven't you asked your colleagues or your advisor?

Comment: Yes! Always good to provide the name of the journal and to use APA style for referencing.

Comment: And if it gets rejected, and you submit to a different journal. Then what?

Comment: @user40491 I have substantially edited the question to capture what I hope you meant to ask in more understandable English. Please check whether I have succeeded. If this is not what you meant to ask, please edit it back or comment here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, when defending your thesis there is no reason to give the names of the journals to which you have submitted papers based on it. It would not benefit you in any way (since they have not been accepted) and you will be embarrassed if the papers are rejected.

Comment: I agree, although I think that there’s a bit of a difference between advertising this and responding to being asked. I think this answer is correct wrt unsolicited sharing. If being asked, I would consider sharing.

Comment: @StellaBiderman I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience of defending my own master thesis and supervision of some others, I can conclude that it is always a good idea to present the papers that you submitted based on content from your thesis (in the main contributions *slide*), pointing out the details of the conference/journal, even when they are, yet, under review (just point out that in the presentation).

In some case it may be helpful to have a *preprint version* attached to your thesis document or in some repository such as [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/).